# Join + Leave with a Discord bot in Python

Tags: python, discord

I've made these two commands, one for leaving the channel that the bot is currently connected to, and one for joining the command sender's channel.

The problem is that neither of them are working. How can I fix this?

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def leave(ctx):
    server = ctx.message.guild.voice_client
    await server.disconnect()

@bot.command(pass_context = True)
async def join(ctx):
    channel = ctx.message.author.voice.voice_channel
    await bot.join_voice_channel(channel)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though you're using old documentation or tutorials, along with some new documentation.

Some [changes from `0.16.x` to rewrite](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html):

- You should use [`VoiceChannel.join()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html#models-are-stateful) instead of [`Client.join_voice_channel()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/async/api.html#discord.Client.join_voice_channel)
- Shortcuts are available when using [`Context`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context). In your case, [`ctx.guild`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context.guild) instead of `ctx.message.guild`.
- All [voice changes](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html#voice-changes)
- Context is [automatically passed](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html#context-changes) - there isn't any need for `pass_context=True`

Rewriting your code - with some conditions to check if the author is in a voice channel:

```py
@bot.command()
async def leave(ctx):
    if ctx.guild.voice_client.is_connected(): # Checking that they're in a vc
        await ctx.guild.voice_client.disconnect()
    else:
        await ctx.send("Sorry, I'm not connected to a voice channel at the moment.")

@bot.command()
async def join(ctx):
    if ctx.author.voice:
        await ctx.author.voice.channel.connect() # This will error if the bot doesn't have sufficient permissions
    else:
        await ctx.send("You're not connected to a channel at the moment.")
```

---

**References:**

- [New documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)
- [`VoiceClient.is_connected()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.VoiceClient.is_connected)
- [`VoiceClient.disconnect()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.VoiceClient.disconnect)
- [`Context.send()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context.send)
- [`Member.voice`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.voice)
- [`VoiceState.channel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.VoiceState.channel)
- [`VoiceChannel.connect()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.VoiceChannel.connect)

Comment: Ok but the consol say : PyNaCl library needed in order to use voice

Comment: Run `pip install PyNaCl` in your cmd prompt. Then `import nacl` into your script. @beyptitloup

Comment: Okay i do that and i tell you the result

Comment: DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nacl'

Comment: right okay, try `pip3 install PyNaCl` instead. And you might also want to consider uninstalling python 2.7 if nothing on your OS depends on it.

Comment: Okay i test that

Comment: Thanks !!! But just question how do I do a search on youtube (with the bot)?

Comment: That's a whole other beast. I'd recommend looking through [this](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/basic_voice.py) example and reading through the documentation of the different libraries to understand what's going on.